# using squeeze theorem on $\sin(\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: calculus

Find
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sin \left(\frac{1}{n}\right).$$

Will it be safe to say that because $0 \leq  \sin(\frac{1}{n})\leq\frac{1}{n}$ the $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sin(\frac{1}{n})=0$?

Comment: Yes, why not? What is the point that bothers you?

Comment: $sin(\frac{1}{n})\leq \frac{1}{n}$ is not right for all $n$

Comment: $\sin x\leq x$ is right for any $x\geq 0$.

Comment: @AlbertoDebernardi but here because X can be negative, I can not say it

Comment: The sine function is odd. Thus, if $x<0$,  $-\sin x \leq |x|$. Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n \geq 1$, then by mean-value theorem we have
$$
0 \leq |\sin \frac{1}{n} - \sin 0| = \sin \frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n}\sup_{0 < t < \frac{1}{n}}|\cos t | \leq \frac{1}{n};
$$
I guess you are not sure about the inequality you use.